# Show that $\Sigma_1=\Sigma_2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let  $(\mathbb{R}^n, \Sigma_1, \mu_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^n, \Sigma_2, \mu_2)$ be  measure spaces where $\mu_1(K)<\infty$ and $\mu_2(K)<\infty$ for both metrics whenever K is a compact set. Let  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the  Borel sets and suppose that $\Sigma_j \supset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n),j=1,2$. Suppose that there exists translation invariant ourter measures  $\mu_j^{*}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n, j=1,2,$ such that $\mu_j^{*}=\mu_j$ on $\Sigma_j, j=1,2$ and that for  $E \in \Sigma_j$

$$\mu_j(E) = \inf\{\mu_j^{*}(\mathcal{O}): E \subset \mathcal{O}, \mathcal{O} \; \textrm{open}\}$$

and that $\mu_1^{*}(E) = 0$ if  and only if  $\mu_2^{*}(E) = 0$.

Now, I would like to show that  $\Sigma_1=\Sigma_2$.
I am also guessing they are Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra but I am not sure how to show that. Any helps would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misinterpreting something, this is false.  Let $\Sigma_1$ be the Borel measurable sets and $\Sigma_2$ be the Lebesgue measurable sets.  Let $\mu_1^*$ and $\mu_2^*$ both be the Lebesgue outer measure and let $\mu_1$ be Lebesgue measure (restricted to Borel sets only) and let $\mu_2$ also be Lebesgue measure.  Then all the properties listed are true, but $\Sigma_1 \neq \Sigma_2$.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thought! I just added a condition that "$\mu_1(K)<\infty$ and $\mu_2(K)<\infty$ for both metrics whenever K is a compact set.". Do you think this makes any difference?

Comment: No, because Lebesgue measure has that property. The same counterexample still holds